# Read , write and notify ble cc2540 ti

Tags: core-bluetooth

in   cc2540     ble    can    read,write     and     notify     options    can    be    enabled    at    a     same    time?  i     only     tried    notify   options.
is  there    any    guidelines    to    be    followed.

Answer (score 0):

yes,the cc2540  read write and notify can be enabled at a same time
[guidelines](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru271f/swru271f.pdf)